# Retrofit 2 How to Make Same Request Multiple Times

Tags: android, http, retrofit2

```
public void makeGetRequest() {


    Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("https://desolate-beach-17272.herokuapp.com");
    Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();


    RetrofitInterface retrofitInterface = retrofit.create(RetrofitInterface.class);


    Call<ResponseBody> call = retrofitInterface.downloadFileByUrl("downloadFile/beach.jpg");


    call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")

        // returns the response if everything is okay
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, final Response<ResponseBody> response) {

            try {
                Log.d("Success" , " " + response.body().bytes().length);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d("FAIL", "oops");

        }
    });
```

I have this code and it makes a get `request` to my server with the `async` method. What I want is to make the same request multiple times. For example, I want to make `get request` 100 times. I don't want to use observables or other external libraries if possible. Is there anyone who can help me with that?

Comment: You want the call to be auto happen after certain time or based on some condition?

Comment: I don't want to happen on some condition. It can start immediately when the app launches and start to queue 100 calls right away.

Comment: Check below I have posted the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make call multiple times just see the below code where I have used methods for this purpose. In onResponse method after performing operation on data you get from server you can make another call to the same API by using a variable sizeOfCall and decrementing it untill it equals to zero. Below is the full code for it.

```
public class RequestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    int sizeOfCall = 100;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_request);

      callAPI();
    }

 private void callAPI(){
    Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("https://desolate-beach-17272.herokuapp.com");
    Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();
    RetrofitInterface retrofitInterface = retrofit.create(RetrofitInterface.class);
    Call<ResponseBody> call = retrofitInterface.downloadFileByUrl("downloadFile/beach.jpg");

    // Call API
    makeGetRequest(call);
}

 private void makeGetRequest(Call<ResponseBody> call) {

call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {

   @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")

    // returns the response if everything is okay
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, final Response<ResponseBody> response) {

        try {
            Log.d("Success", " " + response.body().bytes().length);
            // Perform your operations here and call API againg after that
            sizeOfCall--;
            if (sizeOfCall > 0) {
                callAPI();
                } else {
                 // No more calls needed
                 }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }


            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("FAIL", "oops");

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Would for loop approach be a problem for the async operations?

Comment: Check my Edited answer the `sizeOfCall` variable will be decremented inside `onResponse` method and call will be sent on each response until your call limit completed.

Comment: what your logcat says?

Comment: Check for response what you are getting parse it accordingly.

Comment: There is no problem at the first request, i get the result

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188419/discussion-between-abid-khan-and-wolf).

Answer (score 1):

Create a broadcast reciever and put your retrofit request in that. Now call it using alarm manager.

```
public class YourBroadCastReciever extends BroadcastReceiver{



    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            yourRetrofitCode();

    }

    private void yourRetrofitCode(){
        Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("https://desolate-beach-17272.herokuapp.com");
    Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();


    RetrofitInterface retrofitInterface = retrofit.create(RetrofitInterface.class);


    Call<ResponseBody> call = retrofitInterface.downloadFileByUrl("downloadFile/beach.jpg");


    call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")

        // returns the response if everything is okay
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, final Response<ResponseBody> response) {

            try {
                Log.d("Success" , " " + response.body().bytes().length);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d("FAIL", "oops");

        }
    });

    }
}
```

now call using this code :

```
 Intent sendDeviceInfoIntent = new Intent(this, YourBroadCastReciever.class);
       PendingIntent yourintent= PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, sendDeviceInfoIntent, 0);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()+1000, 60000, yourintent);
```

so that every 5 min this will call your broadcast reciever and this will also works in background

Comment: :- you are answering for the multiple request after certain interval of time and question asked was for the multiple request simultaneously